# Convert GraphQL shorthand notation to respective object?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am working on a GraphQL server setup where it can parse Types passed into it from strings, and I am looking for a solution to convert a string to an appropriate object. For example, if the string here is passed in:

```
type User { id: String, name: String }
```

My function would return the equivelant of running this code:

```
new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: {
    id: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
    name: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
  }
});
```

The key here is to be agnostic, so I could also pass in say, interfaces, and other shorthand and have it return the appropriate object. I have gotten as far as achieving the Abstract Syntax Tree from the `graphql/language` module bu using `graphql_language.parse(str)` function, but I'm unsure where to go from here.

Comment: I'm curious. What is your scenario that needs string to GraphQL type conversion?

Comment: I'm interested in building a system that allows for CRUD of types themselves without modification of the code on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference GraphQL-JS implementation on GitHub already has a function, `buildASTSchema`, that takes a parsed type schema and creates a set of JavaScript objects. So the best way to see how to do it would be to consult that source code on GitHub: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/utilities/buildASTSchema.js

Alternatively, perhaps your tool can be built using that function. Since that repository is maintained by the core GraphQL team, you can be pretty confident that it will be up to date with new additions to the spec.

Edit from comment: If what you're trying to do is generate an executable GraphQL schema/server from the type language string, then you can use the `generateSchema` function from the `graphql-tools` package, as documented here: http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-server/generate-schema.html

Comment: That looks like it would be very useful to me! If there are no better answers in the next few days, this will be the one I accept. Thanks!

Comment: To add to Stubailo's answer: graphql-tools does exactly that (and more) to build not just an object, but an executable. Here's the line in question: https://github.com/apollostack/graphql-tools/blob/607cfcc893c511fe3d7ccbca8da35ce469cc7eb5/src/schemaGenerator.js#L125

Comment: Wow @helfer, that's even more useful to me! Maybe you should put it in a separate answer for yourself, or Stubailo could edit it into his.